# Could not convert String to float in numpy ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have been doing some reading from fer 2013 csv file containing three columns emotion, pixel value and usage. the pixel value is said to have given in string format and I want to rescale my pixel values from 0-255 to between 0-1 , so I need to convert it to int/float and then only I would be able to do any mathematical operations on them.

I first tried to read the csv file using pandas read_csv function and then using iloc I read the value of the pixel value in a variable called x_tr. Then upon printing its value it shows its d type as object.confused on that too.x_tr is numpy ndarray then how should I convert it into integral value.
I tried the x_tr.astype(np.float) but it gave up the error as mentioned in the code.

```
x_tr = train.iloc[:,1].values
x_tr
```

[image: The screenshot of what x_tr contains]

what I tried to convert to float

```
x_tr = train.iloc[:,1].values
x_tr = x_tr.astype(np.float)
```

and what I've got as error

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: They are from a set of 28k images with each image being a size of 48*48 how could I post them as code??

Comment: Post a sample; otherwise, how can we *reproduce* your issue and offer concrete advice?

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert your `pixel` into an array, instead treat it as a simple string. Then use `numpy.fromstring()` method. Here's an example for reference.

```
>>> s = '1 2 3 4'
>>> f = np.fromstring(s, dtype=float, sep=' ')
>>> f
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```